# How to use variable value in select query in hive

Tags: hive

I am finding number of days in a month as below.

```
set ndays=datediff(CONCAT(y, '-', (m + 1), '-', '01'), CONCAT(y, '-', m, '-', '01')) FROM (SELECT month(current_date) as m, year(current_date) as y, day(current_date)) tabl1;
```

I am checking the value.

```
select ${hiveconf:ndays}; --O/P 31
```

I am using this variable in a query and getting error.

```
select
sum(price)/ ${hiveconf:ndays}
from  sales_aly
GROUP BY sales_month;
```

> FAILED: ParseException line 3:0 missing EOF at 'from' near 'tabl1'

Please help me.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

`set` command will not calculate value of this expression: `datediff(CONCAT(y, '-', (m + 1), '-', '01'), CONCAT(y, '-', m, '-', '01')) FROM (SELECT month(current_date) as m, year(current_date) as y, day(current_date)) tabl1` but assigns expression itself as a value. Then when you use variable in the code, expression is substituted instead of variable.

You can calculate your expression in shell and pass it to hive like this:

```
var=$(hive -e "set hive.cli.print.header=false; select datediff(CONCAT(y, '-', (m + 1), '-', '01'), CONCAT(y, '-', m, '-', '01')) FROM (SELECT month(current_date) as m, year(current_date) as y, from tab1 limit 1) tabl1;")
# Then call your script:

hive -hiveconf ndays=$var -f your_script_file_name
```

Address variable inside your script: `${hiveconf:ndays}`

Alternatively you can use macro. See this: http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/hive/trunk/ql/src/test/queries/clientpositive/macro.q

Comment: Hi, I have tried this but not working.cat nds.ksh
var=$(hive -e "datediff(CONCAT(y, '-', (m + 1), '-', '01'), CONCAT(y, '-', m, '-', '01')) FROM (SELECT month(current_date) as m, year(current_date) as y, day(current_date)) tabl1;")

select
sum(price)/ ${hiveconf:ndays}
from  sales_aly
GROUP BY sales_month;

hive -hiveconf ndays=$var -f tt.hql    please help me

Comment: 1. Prepare your script file:
select sum(price)/ ${hiveconf:ndays} from sales_aly GROUP BY sales_month; 

--file tt.hql end

2. then in your shell script:

var=$(hive -e " set hive.cli.print.header=false; select datediff(CONCAT(y, '-', (m + 1), '-', '01'), CONCAT(y, '-', m, '-', '01')) FROM (SELECT month(current_date) as m, year(current_date) as y, from tab1 limit 1) tabl1;") ;
#use variable in the script;


hive -hiveconf ndays=$var -f tt.hql

Comment: See also this link: https://netezzaadmin.wordpress.com/2013/09/25/passing-parameters-to-hive-scripts/

Comment: In your example: select ${hiveconf:ndays}; --O/P 31  the variable first substituted with initial value - this exactly string: `(datediff(CONCAT(y, '-', (m + 1), '-', '01'), CONCAT(y, '-', m, '-', '01')) FROM (SELECT month(current_date) as m, year(current_date) as y, day(current_date)) tabl1);`  Then you adding `select ` at the beginning and executing the whole sentence with `select ' at the beginning.

Comment: Hi,
I have tried the below procedure.
step1 : cat >nds.ksh
var=$(hive -e " set hive.cli.print.header=false; select datediff(CONCAT(y, '-', (m + 1), '-', '01'), CONCAT(y, '-', m, '-', '01')) FROM (SELECT month(current_date) as m, year(current_date) as y, day(current_date)) tabl1;");

--this is giving 30 

step2:

select
sum(price)/ '${hiveconf:ndays}'
from  sales_aly
GROUP BY sales_month;

step3:
hive -hiveconf "ndays"="$var" -f tt.hql 

This is  sum(price)/ '${hiveconf:ndays}' is giving the result NULL.

Please help me.

Thanks

Comment: You do not need quote `${hiveconf:ndays}` variable inside script because it's integer, not string. Check the variable passed correctly inside hql script: just `select ${hiveconf:ndays} ;` or ` ! echo  ${hiveconf:ndays}`

Comment: Hi,
I have tried this.

select ${hiveconf:ndays} ;
got the error

FAILED: ParseException line 1:8 cannot recognize input near '<EOF>' '<EOF>' '<EOF>' in select clause 
Please help me.

Thanks.

Comment: try this: ` ! echo ${hiveconf:ndays};` inside the script

Comment: Syntactically select ${hiveconf:ndays}; is correct when variable is set. I have just checked. Most probably the variable is not set. have you checked $var is not empty?

Comment: Hi,

I have tried this.
 cat nds.ksh
var=$(hive -e " set hive.cli.print.header=false; select datediff(CONCAT(y, '-', (m + 1), '-', '01'), CONCAT(y, '-', m, '-', '01')) FROM (SELECT month(current_date) as m, year(current_date) as y, day(current_date)) tabl1;")
echo $var

ksh nds.ksh
I got value 30.

Again I tried echo$var its not giving anything.

Thanks

Comment: If it's possible could please provide the steps needs to be followed.

Comment: So the problem is  var is not set. Maybe you are calling hive command from a subshell where var does not exist?

Comment: Hi,

I am doing this.
Please let me know am I missing anything.

In UNIX prompt

step1 : cat >nds.ksh 
var=$(hive -e " set hive.cli.print.header=false; select datediff(CONCAT(y, '-', (m + 1), '-', '01'), CONCAT(y, '-', m, '-', '01')) FROM (SELECT month(current_date) as m, year(current_date) as y, day(current_date)) tabl1;"); 

step2:cat >tt.hql
select ${hiveconf:ndays};

step3: hive -hiveconf ndays=$var -f tt.hql 

Please help me.
Thanks.

Comment: Ok, let's try one more time, I will make simplified example. 1) create HQL script file: vi tt.hql   File content is: select ${hiveconf:ndays};  2) create script file: vi nds.ksh  File contents is three lines var=$(hive -e " set hive.cli.print.header=false; select 30;");
echo $var
hive -hiveconf ndays=$var -f tt.hql
#End of file

Comment: and now run it: chmod u+x nds.ksh  - make this file executable first

Comment: ./nds.ksh

-skipped some Hive output here
OK
Time taken: 0.724 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
30  -----this is printed variable $var from second line of the script

-skipped some Hive output here
OK
30 --This is printed by select statement from the tt.hql

Comment: Once more the contents of the shell file (lines separated by \n): var=$(hive -e " set hive.cli.print.header=false; select 30;"); \n
echo $var \n
hive -hiveconf ndays=$var -f tt.hql

Comment: Hi,

Thanks for your solution.
It's working fine.

In the below query instead of "current_date" I want to pass the date as parameter.

var=$(hive -e " set hive.cli.print.header=false; select datediff(CONCAT(y, '-', (m + 1), '-', '01'), CONCAT(y, '-', m, '-', '01')) FROM (SELECT month(current_date) as m, year(current_date) as y, day(current_date)) tabl1;");

Please help me ASAP.

Thanks

Comment: You can use shell variables inside queries: some_date='2016-09-11'; result=$(hive -e " set hive.cli.print.header=false; select $some_date");

Comment: Hi ,

I have tried this it's priniting NULL.
Please help me.

cat > nds.ksh
run_date=$1
var=$(hive -e " set hive.cli.print.header=false; select datediff(CONCAT(y, '-', (m + 1), '-', '01'), CONCAT(y, '-', m, '-', '01')) FROM (SELECT month(CAST('${hiveconf:run_date}') as m, year('${hiveconf:run_date}') as y, day('${hiveconf:run_date}')) tabl1;")
echo $var
ksh nds.ksh 2016-09-11
Thanks

Comment: hiveconf will not work inside shell with hive-e. hiveconf is for hive -f... For hive -e option use shell variables $variable like in my previous comment.

Comment: Hi,
As you said I have use as $variable.
Still it's printing as NULL.
cat > nds.ksh
run_date=$1
var=$(hive -e " set hive.cli.print.header=false; select datediff(CONCAT(y, '-', (m + 1), '-', '01'), CONCAT(y, '-', m, '-', '01')) FROM (SELECT month($run_date) as m, year($run_date) as y, day($run_date)) tabl1;")
echo $var

ksh nds.ksh '2016-09-11'

Please help me.

Thanks

Comment: Sorry man, I cannot debug your scripts here. How have you checked that the variable is passed correctly? BTW why are you doing this in such way? Why don't you just using date shell command to format your date then pass it to your hive script using hiveconf?

Comment: Hi,

Date is not static.
I want to find the number of days for a given date.
I will be executing for different dates.
SO that I cannot use shell command date.
Please help me.

Thanks,

Comment: It seems like you are trying to format some date, and maybe perform some calculation with date using Hive then save result and then again pass it to hive as a parameter to run some script.  You can format any date and perform date calculations using shell date command, look at the documentation on date command, it's not just static date, it can perform complex date calculations. then pass the result to hive script using hiveconf. It is much more faster then running hive for date formatting/date math. Anyway I have demonstrated you how to pass variables to your hive scripts.

Comment: Hi,I have fixed it. Sorry to bother you.Thanks for your help

Comment: Hi ,
Finally we have to execute as hive script as per our requirement.
I have tried this.It's not working.

cat >exec_script.hql
!ksh nds.ksh 

hive -f exec_script.hql 2016-09-11

Please help me.

Thanks